# Angular ngrx dynamic form reset the form value

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using dynamic forms

```
 <app-form [question]="question" [form]="sectionConfig.form" [connectPayload]="sectionConfig.connectPayload"></app-form>
```

On click of button, I am trying to make the form values null, in console I am getting values has been reset(it gives me null).
I am using `form.reset({}).` to do that.

But on UI I still see the values.

I think its because of `[connectPayload]` and values are saving into state. How can I delete the values from state in case of dynamic forms.

I need to save the values into state but I need to delete all the values on click of button

Comment: I recommend avoiding that kind of DOM manipulation with Angular. You could achieve the desired result with structural directives, like ngIf and ngFor. See the documentation about [Angular Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Comment: The dom manipulation is working in the above stackblitz link. am i missing something ?